# What OAuth endpoint should be used to query user information from the Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, add-in, office-js

I'm writing a Word add-in. The add-in will be a paid add-in that can be purchased by an organization (Office 365 tenant) or an individual.

#### Licensing

Once purchased a user will have to authenticate. To ensure the user is licences to use the add-in I will validate either by

1. If an individual purchaser: looking up id or email associated with user's Microsoft account
2. If an organizational user: look up tenant id and reference number of licenses

I don't expect Microsoft to provide/store any licensing data. The licensing data (terms and ids) will be kept in my own database.

#### Authentication

Until SSO is out of Preview, I'm planning on using the `Authenticator` from [`office-js-helpers`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers#authentication), to get the information of the user that has signed in to my add-in.

In the helper docs they list the following possible OAuth strategies:

```
var authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();

// register Microsoft (Azure AD 2.0 Converged auth) endpoint using
authenticator.endpoints.registerMicrosoftAuth('client id here');

// register Azure AD 1.0 endpoint using
authenticator.endpoints.registerAzureADAuth('client id here', 'tenant here');

// register Google endpoint using
authenticator.endpoints.registerGoogleAuth('client id here');

// register Facebook endpoint using
authenticator.endpoints.registerFacebookAuth('client id here');

// register any 3rd-Party OAuth Implicit Provider using
authenticator.endpoints.add('Name of provider', { /* Endpoint Configuration */ })
```

#### Graph API

I understand that once a user is authenticated I will receive an authentication token which I can use to query the Graph API for the user's information.

## Question

My question is which OAuth strategy will respond with a token to the Graph API that will return information for:

1. Individual users with a Microsoft account
2. Organizational users associated to a tenant id

?

Is there any difference between the

```
Microsoft (Azure AD 2.0 Converged auth) endpoint
```

and the

```
Azure AD 1.0 endpoint
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are quite a few differences. At a high-level, these are:

v1 endpoint:

- Only supports AAD accounts. It does not support MSA/Outlook.com/Live account types.
- Uses "Resources" instead of "Scopes"
- Requires pre-defining the permission scopes you want in the registration
- Supported by nearly all Microsoft REST API's (not just Microsoft Graph)

v2 endpoint:

- Supports both AAD and MSA accounts
- Uses "Scopes" instead of "Resources"
- Permission scopes can be dynamically requested at runtime *or* predefined (note that for service/daemon apps using Client Credentials, you must predefine them).
- Supported by a smaller set of APIs today (although to be fair, most APIs are heading to Graph over time).

*Note: This is a super-high-level-skip-a-lot-of-detail list but it covers most of the core differences.*

Comment: So if a user registers with either an  AAD or MSA account and then logs in to v2 I'll receive the registration user id (and tenant id if part of a group)? This sounds more suitable to my use-case, right?

Comment: Does Graph API support v2 tokens?

Comment: Correct. If you want to authenticate both AAD and MSA users, then you'll need to use the v2 endpoint.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Graph supports both v1 & v2 access tokens.